# How to handle getFileAsync failed status when submit a file in Officejs add-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working on Office add-in and I want to know what is the best practice to handle `getFileAsync` failure status and what is its reason. And since this error is solved when I reload the add-in, I want to solve this issue in failed case.

The result in this case is:

```
error: {name: "Internal Error", message: "An internal error has occurred.", code: 5001}
status: "failed"
value: undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(OfficeFileType, { sliceSize: 10000 }, result => {
  console.log('submitFile -> result', result);
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    const myFile = result.value;
    const state = {
      file: myFile,
      counter: 0,
      sliceCount: myFile.sliceCount
    };

    console.log(`Getting file of ${myFile.size} bytes`);
    getSlice(state);
    return true;
  }
  console.log(result.status);  // failed
  // try to handle this issue here?
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes. That is the way to handle a "failed" `result.status`.

Comment: How to know what is the problem then? I need more details about this Internal Error.

Comment: thanks @slightlysnarky but its not related :))

Comment: Would you please share a bit more on the following information: 
• Sample Code your scenario, prefer to have script lab gist.
• Which platform are you running on 
• The sample workbook which can repro this error